# how can I take various VARs and place them into a container created in the HTML?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am working on a Jeopardy (quiz game) game for my wife (who is a school teacher). The HTML is set up to have multiple columns and multiple rows.

Example of my HTML:

```
<body>

<div id="container">

<div id="logo" class="center">

<img src="jeoparody.png" />

</div>

<div id="wood" class="center">
    <ul id="categories">
        <li>The Global Age</li>
        <li>Age of Revolutions</li>
        <li>Era of Global Wars</li>
        <li>The Post War Period</li>
        <li>Geography</li>
    </ul>

<div class="clear"></div>

<hr />

<div class="clear"></div>

    <ul id="rowOne">
        <li><a href="#">$100</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">$100</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">$100</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">$100</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">$100</a></li>
    </ul>

<div class="clear"></div>

    <ul id="rowTwo" class="center">
        <li><a href="#">$200</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">$200</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">$200</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">$200</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">$200</a></li>
    </ul>

<div class="clear"></div>

    <ul id="rowThree" class="center">
        <li><a href="#">$300</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">$300</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">$300</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">$300</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">$300</a></li>
    </ul>

<div class="clear"></div>

    <ul id="rowFour" class="center">
        <li><a href="#">$400</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">$400</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">$400</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">$400</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">$400</a></li>
    </ul>

<div class="clear"></div>

    <ul id="rowFive" class="center">
        <li><a href="#">$500</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">$500</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">$500</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">$500</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">$500</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>

<div id="footer" class="center"></div>

</div>

<div id="clueContainer" class="center"></div>

</body>
```

What I am attempting to do is click on the "li" of each row and column and the "a" take me to a container housing the clue. In my jQuery code I have accomplished this feat for the first column; however, I am unable to write the code that will accomplish this for every column.

JQuery code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    var columnOne = {
        "$100": "On the world political map, where were some of the major states and     empires located about 1500 A.D. (C.E.)?",
        "$200": "What were the artistic, literary, and intellectual ideas of the Renaissance?",
        "$300": "Where were the five world religions located around 1500 A.D. (C.E.)?",
        "$400": "What were the regional trading patterns about 1500 A.D. (C.E.)?",
        "$500": "Why were the regional trading patterns important?",
    };

var columnTwo = {
    "100": "What were the artistic, literary, and intellectual ideas of the Renaissance?",
    "200": "B",
    "300": "C",
    "400": "D",
    "500": "E",
};

var columnThree = {
    "100": "A",
    "200": "B",
    "300": "C",
    "400": "D",
    "500": "E",
};

var columnFour = {
    "100": "D",
    "200": "B",
    "300": "C",
    "400": "D",
    "500": "E",
};

var columnFive = {
    "100": "A",
    "200": "B",
    "300": "C",
    "400": "D",
    "500": "E",
};  

$('li').on('click', 'a', function () {
    var foo = $(this).text();
    $("#clueContainer").text( columnOne[foo] );
});

$("#rowTwo").on("click", "a", function () {
    var foo2 = $(this).text( columnTwoTwo[foo2] );
});

$("#container").click(function(){
$("#container").hide(function(){
    $("#clueContainer").show(function(){
    });
});

$("#clueContainer").click(function(){
$("#clueContainer").hide(function(){
    $("#container").show(function(){
    });
});
});

});
});
```

Could someone be willing to help me accomplish my goal or at least help me figure out what I am doing wrong?

CSS:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'korinna_btregular';
    src: url('fontsJ/korinna_regular_bt-webfont.eot');
    src: url('fontsJ/korinna_regular_bt-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
         url('fontsJ/korinna_regular_bt-webfont.woff') format('woff'),
         url('fontsJ/korinna_regular_bt-webfont.ttf') format('truetype'),
         url('fontsJ/korinna_regular_bt-webfont.svg#korinna_btregular') format('svg');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;}

body{background-color: #000;}

hr{border: 3px solid #200b02;}

#wood{width: 960px;
height: auto;
background-image: url(woodGrain.png);
position: relative;
border: 3px solid #200b02;
-webkit-box-shadow: 5px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 1);}

#container{width: 100%;
margin: 5px;
padding: 5px;}

.center{width: 960px;
margin: 0px auto;}

.clear{clear: both;}

#logo{width: 960px;
height: 250px;
padding-top: 30px;
display: block;
text-align: center;
vertical-align: middle;
line-height: 250px;
background-color: #002290;}

#categories li{width: 175px;
height: 100px;
margin: 0px 5px 5px -8px;
display: inline-block;
border: 1px solid #fff;
color: #fff;
font-family: 'korinna_btregular';
text-transform: uppercase;
font-size: 14px;
vertical-align: middle;
border-radius: 10px 10px;
text-align: center;
vertical-align: middle;
line-height: 100px;
background-color: #002290;
-webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 3px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 1);}

#categories a{color: #fff;
text-decoration: none;}

#rowOne li{width: 175px;
height: 100px;
margin: 5px 5px 0px -8px;
display: inline-block;
border: 1px solid #fff;
color: #e6ca8b;
font-family: 'korinna_btregular';
text-transform: uppercase;
font-size: 48px;
font-weight: bold;
border-radius: 10px 10px;
text-align: center;
vertical-align: middle;
line-height: 100px;
background-color: #002290;
-webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 4px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 1);}

#rowOne a{color: #fcd830;
text-decoration: none;}

#rowOne li:hover{background-color: #a3bbfb;}

#rowTwo li{width: 175px;
height: 100px;
margin: 0px 5px 5px -8px;
display: inline-block;
border: 1px solid #fff;
font-family: 'korinna_btregular';
text-transform: uppercase;
font-size: 48px;
font-weight: bold;
border-radius: 10px 10px;
text-align: center;
vertical-align: middle;
line-height: 100px;
background-color: #002290;
-webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 4px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 1);}

#rowTwo a{color: #fcd830;
text-decoration: none;}

#rowTwo li:hover{background-color: #a3bbfb;}

#rowThree li{width: 175px;
height: 100px;
margin: 5px 5px 5px -8px;
display: inline-block;
border: 1px solid #fff;
font-family: 'korinna_btregular';
text-transform: uppercase;
font-size: 48px;
font-weight: bold;
border-radius: 10px 10px;
text-align: center;
vertical-align: middle;
line-height: 100px;
background-color: #002290;
-webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 4px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 1);}

#rowThree a{color: #fcd830;
text-decoration: none;}

#rowThree li:hover{background-color: #a3bbfb;}

#rowFour li{width: 175px;
height: 100px;
margin: 5px 5px 5px -8px;
display: inline-block;
border: 1px solid #fff;
font-family: 'korinna_btregular';
text-transform: uppercase;
font-size: 48px;
font-weight: bold;
border-radius: 10px 10px;
text-align: center;
vertical-align: middle;
line-height: 100px;
background-color: #002290;
-webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 5px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 1);}

#rowFour a{color: #fcd830;
text-decoration: none;}

#rowFour li:hover{background-color: #a3bbfb;}

#rowFive li{width: 175px;
height: 100px;
margin: 5px 5px 20px -8px;
display: inline-block;
border: 1px solid #fff;
font-family: 'korinna_btregular';
text-transform: uppercase;
font-size: 48px;
font-weight: bold;
border-radius: 10px 10px;
text-align: center;
vertical-align: middle;
line-height: 100px;
background-color: #002290;
-webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 5px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 1);}

#rowFive a{color: #fcd830;
text-decoration: none;}

#rowFive li:hover{background-color: #a3bbfb;}

#footer{width: 960px;
height: 20px;
background-color:#002290;}

/***Clues***/

#clueContainer{width: 900px;
height: 500px;
margin-top: 150px;
padding: 200px 100px 0 100px;
color: #fff;
font-family: 'korinna_btregular';
text-transform: uppercase;
font-size: 54px;
border: 1px solid #fff;
border-radius: 25px 25px;
background-color: #002290;
-webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 5px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 1);
display: none;}
```

Comment: `var foo2 = $(this).text( columnTwoTwo[foo2] );` **columnTwoTwo**? A typo perhaps

Comment: One thing that's wrong: Your objects have commas at the end of the last property. Objects should only have commas **in between** properties: `{ prop1: 'val1', prop2: 'val2' }`.

Comment: Both of the previous comments reveal typos / code misuse that a tool like [JSHint](http://www.jshint.com/) would show you.

Comment: I have corrected the typos; however, I am still not understanding how to get the various VARs to show up, as of now, only the first VAR shows up when I click on the link.

Comment: The object of Jeopardy is to get clues from the various levels (i.e. "100", "200", etc.). Now when I click on the level ("100", "200", etc.), I would like the corresponding clue (or question) to appear in the box that shows up. Therefore, every box with a dollar amount on it needs to have a corresponding clue (or question). Now, these clues are located in various VARs and I would like to pull the specific clue corresponding with the dollar amount in each square.

Comment: I'm sorry but I don't know how Jeopardy's mechanics work. So can you please elaborate on your question/objective? And try to minimize the code to just the parts your'e having trouble with OR add comments on those parts..:)

Comment: Would you care to provide your CSS as well? I'm working out a solution...

Comment: Which part would you like to look at?

Comment: The part that styles your HTML?

Comment: I added the CSS to the original question.

Answer (score 0):

This one works:

```
$('li a').click(function () {
    var foo = $(this).html();
    //for debugging only, remove once it is working
    alert(foo);
    $("#clueContainer").html( columnOne[foo] );
});
```

Comment: It does not do what I want it to. I would like to get the code to pull from the VARs of each row and place them in the container when I click on the various boxes.

Comment: Well, this part was not working either. You should apply the same JS code to you other functions. You can also create a css selector for each row and change the array in it (columnOne). Also you can create 2D arrays, so you can use with row and column IDs.